# Core Data: Writing Batch of Records to Disk In Background

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have a main application that has a core data database. I'm doing all of the app's activity in the main context but I create a child context to handle background syncing that could add as many as 30,000 records to the database. Everything works great and the background sync doesn't slow the main app down until it actually goes to save the context, then the app is unresponsive for a few seconds while Core Data writes the records to disk.

Is there any way to work around this issue so that a large disk save doesn't affect the UI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read through [this link](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/07/multi-context-coredata/) to learn a little bit more about saving core data records in the background. Essentially, your main context is a child of a background context that does the actual writing. This way, your main thread won't get blocked to write stuff to disk. It might, however, be temporarily blocked when merging/importing changes from a background context.